# MySQL avg and left join

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to combine these two queries? Adding another left join didn't work.

```
 select distinct 
     p.products_id,
     p.products_image,
     pd.products_name, 
     m.manufacturers_name,
     p.manufacturers_id,
     p.products_price,
     p.products_tax_class_id,
     IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) as specials_new_products_price,
     IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) as final_price
 from products_description pd,
      products p
      left join manufacturers m on p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id
      left join specials s on p.products_id = s.products_id, products_to_categories p2c
 where
          p.products_status = '1'
      and p.products_id = p2c.products_id
      and pd.products_id = p2c.products_id
      and pd.language_id = '1'
      and p2c.categories_id = '17'
 order by p.sort_order
 //-------------------
 select avg(reviews_rating) as average_rating from reviews where
 products_id = '31' and reviews_status = '1'
```

The first one is getting product details and the second one is getting the average rating from reviews table.

Comment: What does the result of each query look like? What would the combined result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try it-

```
SELECT p.products_id, p.products_image, pd.products_name, m.manufacturers_name, p.manufacturers_id, p.products_price, p.products_tax_class_id, IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) AS specials_new_products_price, IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) AS final_price, AVG(rvw.reviews_rating) AS average_ratings  
FROM products p
JOIN products_to_categories p2c ON p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
JOIN products_description pd ON pd.products_id = p2c.products_id
LEFT JOIN manufacturers m ON p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id 
LEFT JOIN specials s ON p.products_id = s.products_id 
LEFT JOIN reviews rvw ON rvw.products_id=p.products_id 
WHERE p.products_status = '1' AND pd.language_id = '1' AND p2c.categories_id = '17' 
GROUP BY p.products_id 
ORDER BY p.sort_order;
```

Note: Always first mention all inner/comma join tables then left join.

Answer (score 0):

How about just put the second query as `select item` in the first query?

```
select 
    distinct p.products_id, p.products_image, pd.products_name, 
    m.manufacturers_name, p.manufacturers_id, p.products_price, p.products_tax_class_id, 
    IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) as specials_new_products_price, 
    IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) as final_price,
    (select avg(reviews_rating) as average_rating from reviews where products_id = '31' and reviews_status = '1') as average_rating
from products_description pd, products p left join manufacturers m on p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id left join specials s on p.products_id = s.products_id, products_to_categories p2c 
where p.products_status = '1' and p.products_id = p2c.products_id and pd.products_id = p2c.products_id and pd.language_id = '1' and p2c.categories_id = '17' 
order by p.sort_order
```

Answer (score 0):

M no great in queries, but will give a try. 
 First, I would like to know if there is a relationship between the tables 'REVIEWS' and 'PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION'. If Yes, then your combined query could be :

```
select distinct p.products_id, p.products_image, pd.products_name, m.manufacturers_name, p.manufacturers_id, p.products_price, p.products_tax_class_id,  IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) as specials_new_products_price,   IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) as final_price ,  avg(rv.reviews_rating) as average_rating   from products_description pd, reviews rv , manufacturers m, products p, specials s, products_to_categories p2c  where pd.products_id =  rv.products_id   and p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id  and p.products_id = s.products_id  and p.products_status = '1'   and p.products_id = p2c.products_id  and pd.products_id = p2c.products_id   and pd.language_id = '1'   and p2c.categories_id = '17'  and rv.products_id = '31'  and rv.reviews_status = '1'  order by p.sort_order;
```